# React Lifting State of Functional Components within loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I am trying to make use of functional components but have trouble lifting the state. This involves a list of child MessageWithContext components inside of a parent component Chat. I don't know how many MessageWithContext there can be and they are rendered within a loop. As I understand I cannot put functional components with hooks inside of a loop since that violates rules of hooks.

The particular feature I am working on allows the user to click on a message to show context of the message like time and sender by changing the component itself.

Here's some code:

Chat.tsx:

```
    
    // Get all chat related values and methods from useChat hook 
    const {
        currentMessages, conversations, activeConversation, setActiveConversation,  sendMessage, getUser, currentMessage, setCurrentMessage,
        sendTyping, setCurrentUser
    } = useChat();
    const [detailedMessages, setDetailedMessages] = useState([false]);



    {activeConversation && currentMessages.map( (g:MessageGroup) => <MessageGroup              key={g.id} direction={g.direction}>
                    <MessageGroup.Messages>
                        {g.messages.map((m:ChatMessage<MessageContentType>) =>
//here I'd like to set the show detail prop based on a reference to the message
                            <MessageWithContext key={m.id} m={m} showDetail={detailedMessages} setShowDetail={setDetailedMessages}/>
                        )}
```

MessageWithContext:

```
interface IMessageWithContext {
    m : ChatMessage<MessageContentType>
    showDetail : boolean[]
    setShowDetail : SetStateAction<any>
}
export const MessageWithContext = (props: IMessageWithContext) => {

    //here I want to change the state of Chat.tsx with some kind of reference to the Message and its state
    const updateShow = (show : boolean) => {
        props.setShowDetail(show)
    }
    return (
        <>
            {!props.showDetail &&
            <div onClick={() => updateShow(true)}>
                <Message key={props.m.id} model={{
                    type: "html",
                    payload: props.m.content
                }}/></div>
            }
            {props.showDetail &&
            <div >
                <Message key={props.m.id} model={{
                    type: "html",
                    payload: props.m.content
                }}>
                    <Message.Header sender={props.m.senderId} sentTime={"just now"}>
                    </Message.Header>
                    </Message>
            </div>}
        </>
    );
```

How can I make it so the updateShow function within MessageWithContext updates detailedMessages and setDetailedMessages with an array of booleans that are somehow linked to those particular MessageWithContext componets?

Comment: `MessageWithContext` can have state via the state kook. That isn't a violation of the rules of hooks. Why do you think it is, or why do you want to lift that state? It seems like it's in the right place.

Comment: @JakeWorth the MessageWithContext is inside of a loop and when new messages were added the number of hook calls was wrong and I would get this error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render".

Comment: Thanks for the info. To understand why that's happening, we'd need to see your `MessageWithContext` with hooks implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I changed the code to include:

'''
const [showDetail, toggleShowDetail] = useState(false);
'''
and used those and this time it works as expected! Follow-up question that relates to the original (if possible): What if I then allow a user to for example respond to a message. How could I go about selecting multiple MessageWithContext components from Chat? I want to be able to track which messages have been selected to be able to use content of each of them. Thanks.

Comment: That would be a candidate for lifting state. A comment on this question wouldn't be the right place for me to solve that problem.